# Cannsandra Driver & jnr-Unixsocket - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider

Tags: java, cassandra, unix-socket, jnr

I am using cassandra and jnr-unix socket in my project and both uses jnr-ffi. Not getting any error in my local, but getting error in test env.

The versions are,

```
Cassandra version - 3.3.2 
jnr-unixsocket - 0.12
```

Error happens on calling UnixSocketChannel.open() from my code.

Code from the hierarchy,

```
public ApacheUnixSocket() throws IOException {
        this.inner = UnixSocketChannel.open();
        this.addr = null;
    }
```

The complete trace is as follows. This error happens only when i call Unisocket, but rest all looks good. Service starts as expected and able to communicate with cassandra db using the driver. Still, i see cassandra trace also. Bit confusing ...

**Error :-**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider
    at jnr.ffi.provider.InvalidProvider$1.loadLibrary(InvalidProvider.java:48)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:290)
    at jnr.unixsocket.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:76)
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.<init>(UnixSocketChannel.java:94)
    at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.open(UnixSocketChannel.java:49)
    at com.test.service.docker.ApacheUnixSocket.<init>(ApacheUnixSocket.java:36)
    at com.test.service.docker.UnixConnectionSocketFactory.createSocket(UnixConnectionSocketFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at com.test.service.docker.DockerClient.getData(DockerClient.java:123)
    at com.test.service.docker.DockerClient.updateContainerMetrics(DockerClient.java:88)
    at com.test.service.docker.DockerContainerMetrics.refreshDockerStats(DockerContainerMetrics.java:109)
    at com.test.service.docker.DockerContainerMetrics.lambda$start$1(DockerContainerMetrics.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.<clinit>(FFIProvider.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.create(LibraryLoader.java:73)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native$LibCLoader.<clinit>(Native.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native.isGettimeofdayAvailable(Native.java:190)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory.newInstance(Clock.java:51)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies.defaultTimestampGenerator(Policies.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies$Builder.build(Policies.java:286)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1317)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:113)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1335)
    at com.test.data.cassandra.spring.boot.CassandraAutoConfiguration$CassandraBuilderFactory.buildCluster(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$OptionalDependencyFactory.createOptionalDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.service.Application.main(Application.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No such file or directory
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:364)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:254)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.<clinit>(StubLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.<clinit>(Foreign.java:45)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:242)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.<init>(AbstractRuntime.java:48)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:41)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NativeRuntime.java:53)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.<clinit>(FFIProvider.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.create(LibraryLoader.java:73)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native$LibCLoader.<clinit>(Native.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native.isGettimeofdayAvailable(Native.java:190)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory.newInstance(Clock.java:51)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies.defaultTimestampGenerator(Policies.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies$Builder.build(Policies.java:286)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1317)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:113)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1335)
    at com.test.cassandra.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CassandraAutoConfiguration$CassandraBuilderFactory.buildCluster(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$OptionalDependencyFactory.createOptionalDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.service.Application.main(Application.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/libjffi-1.2.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromBootPath(StubLoader.java:316)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:249)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.<clinit>(StubLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.<clinit>(Foreign.java:45)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.lookupTypeInfo(Type.java:242)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type$Builtin.getTypeInfo(Type.java:237)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.resolveSize(Type.java:155)
    at com.kenai.jffi.Type.size(Type.java:138)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$TypeDelegate.size(NativeRuntime.java:178)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.AbstractRuntime.<init>(AbstractRuntime.java:48)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.<init>(NativeRuntime.java:41)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NativeRuntime.java:53)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime.getInstance(NativeRuntime.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.getInstance(FFIProvider.java:68)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider$SystemProviderSingletonHolder.<clinit>(FFIProvider.java:57)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.FFIProvider.getSystemProvider(FFIProvider.java:35)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.create(LibraryLoader.java:73)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native$LibCLoader.<clinit>(Native.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native.isGettimeofdayAvailable(Native.java:190)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory.newInstance(Clock.java:51)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies.defaultTimestampGenerator(Policies.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies$Builder.build(Policies.java:286)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1317)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:113)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1335)
    at com.test.cassandra.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CassandraAutoConfiguration$CassandraBuilderFactory.buildCluster(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? I am getting same issue.